# Understanding a proof by Gossner (1998) - see sections $5$, $6$ and $7$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, game-theory, information-theory, cryptography

The following definitions are taken from the paper of [Gossner (2000)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.685.4204&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I want to understand how he proves the theorem that is the main result in his work. I give four definitions and the theorem which is based on them.

$\textit{Definition 1:}$ $I$ is a finite set of players and and $G=((S_i)_{i=1}^I,g)$ is a compact game, that is given by a compact set of strategies $S_i$ for each player $i$ and by a continuous payoff function $g:S(=\times S_i) \to \mathbb{R}^{I}$. Also the mixed set of strategies is defined as $\Sigma_i=\Delta(S_i)$ which is a standard way in game theory.

$\textit{Definition 2:}$ The information structure $\mathbb{I}=((X_i)_{i=1}^{I},\mu)$ is given by a finite set of signals $X_i$ for each $i$ and by a probability measure $\mu$ over $X$. When $x$ is drawn according to $\mu$, player $i$ is informed about the coordinate $x_i$.

$\textit{Definition 3:}$ A communication mechanism is a triple $\mathbb{C}=((T_i)_{i=1}^I, (Y_i)_{i=1}^I , l )$, where $T_i$ is $i's$ finite set of messages, $Y_i$ is $i's$ finite set of signals, and $l: T\to \Delta(Y)$ is the signal function. When $t$ is the profile of messages sent by the players to the mechanism, $y\in Y$ is drawn according to $l(\cdot|t)$ and player $i$ is informed of $y_i$. $\mathbb{T}_i=\Delta(T_i)$ represents the set of mixed messages for player $i$ and $l$ is extended to $\mathbb{T}$ by $l(y|\tau)=\mathbb{E}_{\tau} l(y|t)$.

In this place I can define the protocol

$\textit{Definition 4:}$ For a given communication mechanism $\mathbb{C}$, the protocol is a pair $(\tau,\phi)$, such that:

- a translation $\phi=(\phi_i)_{i=1}^I$ is a family of mappings $\phi_i: Y_i\to \Delta(X_i)$
- and $\tau$ is a profile of mixed messsages

In his paper Gossner proves a theorem which is his main result and it is the following

$\textit{Theorem:}$ $(\tau,\phi)$ is secure if and only if

- For every player $i$ and $\tau_i^{'}\in\mathbb{T}_i$, $m(\tau_i^{'})=m(\tau_i)$
- For every player $i$ and $\tau_i^{'}\in\mathbb{T}_i$, $\alpha_i\supset \gamma_{\tau_{i}^{'}}$

the function $m(\tau_i^{'})$ denotes the marginal of $P_{(\tau_{i}^{'},\tau_{-i})}$ on $X_{-i}$ where
$$P_{(\tau_{i}^{'},\tau_{-i})}(y,x)=l(y|(\tau_{i}^{'},\tau_{-i}))\phi(x|y)$$
and $m(\tau_i^{'})$ is the probability over players other than $i$'s translated signals when they follow the protocol $(\tau,\phi)$ and when $i$'s messages are distributed according to $\tau_{i}^{'}$.

The second bullet of the theorem refers to the comparison of statistical experiments due to Blackwell theorem in statistical expiriments, in order to compare different informations of a player on other's signals. It's meaning is that if $\alpha_i\supset \gamma_{\tau_{i}^{'}}$ then the statistical expiriment $\alpha_i$ is more informative than $\gamma_{\tau_{i}^{'}}$.

$\textit{Question:}$ Can anybody proove the theorem? In the paper he uses different methods to make the proof, but I do not care which one could someone use to proove it or even he\she could find an intuitive way to explain one of them. I strugle to understand his notation.

$\textit{Hint:}$ In order to defince incentives for the players not to change their messages or compute the new messages from the communication procedure differently the authos makes a comparision between the N.E. of the  basic game extended by the communicaition mechanism with respect to the extended game by the information generated by the protocol.

Comment: Noting that you did not define either $\alpha_i$ nor $\gamma'_{\tau_i}$, I looked into the paper to find them, where I also discovered you misquoted the main theorem, which says instead $\alpha^i \supset \gamma'_{\tau_i}$, where the symbol $\supset$ is given the specific meaning earlier in the paper that $\alpha \supset \beta$ when statistical experiment $\alpha$ gives more information than $\beta$. These are critical definitions to give if you want people to be able to understand your question.

Comment: @PaulSinclair i corrected it...but if you think that something is missing you can edit it I think and mention waht you changed..I dont think that it is a bad thing to make changes. You see that it is too dense as a problem and this makes it even more difficult

Comment: @PaulSinclair anyway...thanks!

Comment: Do not expect others to make changes of significance to your posts. In fact, you should expect others to NOT make such changes. Fixing minor issues such as formatting errors, obvious typographical errors, etc. are what open editing is intended for. But no one other than you truly knows what you mean, so issues that involve the meaning of your post should be brought to your attention for you to adjust, so that you can decide what best fits your intent. I'm sorry, but this question isn't a subject I know much about, though I did want to understand it better before deciding I couldn't help.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am reading this article for weeks and still I have not understand basic things so...no worries. For exaplme, the author defines $\phi$ and calls it translation but why? what is the intuition? he does not clarify this